# Wrap table cell with long word

Tags: html, css

I try to follow the explication here : [How to wrap table cell at a maximum width in full width table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303351/how-to-wrap-table-cell-at-a-maximum-width-in-full-width-table)

But I can't make something works to wrap my "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" line.

```
<table class="my-list table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>User id</th>
            <th>User name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Ad content</th>
            <th>Created at</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>66666</td>
            <td>John Smith</td>
            <td>type1</td>
            <td>99999</td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    Good content with words and real sentences.
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>2015-09-02</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>777777</td>
            <td>Martin  Isabelle</td>
            <td>type2</td>
            <td>888888</td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>2015-09-02</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jfmqgh20/2/

Comment: Related (word-break): http://stackoverflow.com/q/1795109/1207195.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[updated link](https://jsfiddle.net/jfmqgh20/5/)

Css Code:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td div {
    white-space: normal;
    word-break: break-all;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This simple solution fixed a painful problem.

Answer (score 1):

you needed to give the table cell a min and max width not the table head.

```
.my-list {
    max-width: 100%;
}

th {
}

td {
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 150px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1.Add `table-layout:fixed` to table in your original code for `word-wrap`css to work.
https://jsfiddle.net/mpsingh2003/jfmqgh20/12/

Option 2. Use `word-break: break-word;` css property. And also set min-width of td. 
Updated JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mpsingh2003/jfmqgh20/9/